# Azure Durable Functions - OrchestrationTrigger stuck

Tags: azure, azure-functions, serverless, azure-durable-functions

I am new to azure durable functions. I have created a sample azure durable function using vs 2019. I am running default generated azure durable function template code locally with azure storage enumerator and when I run the durable function, the OrchestrationTrigger stuck and not able to resume.

***The hub name is samplehubname. There a pending records present in the samplehubnameInstances azure table but there is no records in the samplehubnameHistory azure table.***

There is no exception and no errors in the code.

**SampleFunction.cs**

```
public static class SampleFunction
{
    [FunctionName("SampleFunction")]
    public static async Task<List<string>> RunOrchestrator(
        [OrchestrationTrigger] IDurableOrchestrationContext context)
    {
        var outputs = new List<string>();

        // Replace "hello" with the name of your Durable Activity Function.
        outputs.Add(await context.CallActivityAsync<string>("SampleFunction_Hello", "Tokyo"));

        // returns ["Hello Tokyo!", "Hello Seattle!", "Hello London!"]
        return outputs;
    }

    [FunctionName("SampleFunction_Hello")]
    public static string SayHello([ActivityTrigger] string name, ILogger log)
    {
        log.LogInformation($"Saying hello to {name}.");
        return $"Hello {name}!";
    }

    [FunctionName("SampleFunction_HttpStart")]
    public static async Task<HttpResponseMessage> HttpStart(
        [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "get", "post")] HttpRequestMessage req,
        [DurableClient] IDurableOrchestrationClient starter,
        ILogger log)
    {
        // Function input comes from the request content.
        string instanceId = await starter.StartNewAsync("SampleFunction", null);

        log.LogInformation($"Started orchestration with ID = '{instanceId}'.");

        return starter.CreateCheckStatusResponse(req, instanceId);
    }
}
```

**local.settings.json**

```
{
  "IsEncrypted": false,
  "Values": {
    "AzureWebJobsStorage": "UseDevelopmentStorage=true",
    "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "dotnet",
    "AzureWebJobsSecretStorageType": "files", //files
    "MyTaskHub": "samplehubname"
  }
}
```

***host.json***

```
{
  "version": "2.0",
  "logging": {
    "applicationInsights": {
      "samplingSettings": {
        "isEnabled": true,
        "excludedTypes": "Request"
      }
    }
  },
  "extensions": {
    "durableTask": {
      "hubName": "%MyTaskHub%"
    }
  }
}
```

**samplehubname-control-03** Message Queue

```
{"$type":"DurableTask.AzureStorage.MessageData","ActivityId":"72b75a34-e403-4772-aed0-fbb10039795a","TaskMessage":{"$type":"DurableTask.Core.TaskMessage","Event":{"$type":"DurableTask.Core.History.ExecutionStartedEvent","OrchestrationInstance":{"$type":"DurableTask.Core.OrchestrationInstance","InstanceId":"f8d0499a4297480c8bdf4a56954861d3","ExecutionId":"2e46b87e4cf74c2dab572d92e012bded"},"EventType":0,"ParentInstance":null,"Name":"Function1","Version":"","Input":"null","Tags":null,"EventId":-1,"IsPlayed":false,"Timestamp":"2021-09-21T15:41:35.0156514Z"},"SequenceNumber":0,"OrchestrationInstance":{"$type":"DurableTask.Core.OrchestrationInstance","InstanceId":"f8d0499a4297480c8bdf4a56954861d3","ExecutionId":"2e46b87e4cf74c2dab572d92e012bded"}},"CompressedBlobName":null,"SequenceNumber":1,"Sender":{"$type":"DurableTask.Core.OrchestrationInstance","InstanceId":"","ExecutionId":""}}
```

Any help will appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If your orchestration code has contain a loop too much, the guidance in our [Eternal orchestration documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/durable/durable-functions-eternal-orchestrations).

In your code there is not much loop available.  So, you need to use the [durable functions eternal orchestrations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/durable/durable-functions-eternal-orchestrations?tabs=csharp#exit-from-an-eternal-orchestration) `TerminateAsync` (.NET) method of the [orchestration client binding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/durable/durable-functions-bindings#orchestration-client) to stop it.

Add your durable function into application insights to check the clear view of issue. It may help to fix the issue.

Check the similar issue [here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-durable-extension/issues/1377).

Try the steps and use fan in/ fan out in durable function [durable functions patterns fan out and fan in](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/durable-functions-patterns-fan-out-and-fan-in/)